# rails 4 routing on root site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm under rails 4 and I've a question about routes.
I'd like to have this situation:

```
/brand-name -> bind to brands#show
/serie-name -> bind to series#show
```

I added this on my routes

```
get '/:id', to: 'brands#show', as: :fe_brand
get '/:id', to: 'series#show', as: :fe_serie
```

but I'm always prompt to brands#show action, I know that it is correct, but I'd like to know if there is a work around for it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to use separate namespaces for brands and series. Try:

`get '/brands/:id', to: 'brands#show', as: :fe_brand`

`get '/series/:id', to: 'series#show', as: :fe_serie`

The way the routes file works is that when a new request comes in the format gets pattern-matched and the first matching route it finds is used. Both of your routes are the same, hence you always get taken to brands show. To test this, if you rearrange those two lines in your routes file you should be taken to `series#show` instead.

Edit:

Since you list brands and series as plural, wouldn't their pages be more like an index than a show? So you could have your desired `/brands` and `/series` direct to their respective index pages and then use id's to like to each individual brand or series.

```
get '/brands',     to: 'brands#index', as: :fe_brands
get '/brands/:id', to: 'brands#show',  as: :show_fe_brand
get '/series',     to: 'series#index', as: :fe_serie
get '/series/:id', to: 'series#show',  as: :show_fe_serie
```